# Are major online travel agencies violating CE 80/2009?

Tags: european-union, air-travel, transportation

Many online travel agencies let you book a flight, but they offer only the lowest fare (for ex. Economy Light). On airline websites there often are higher fares (for ex. Economy Basic, Economy Basic Plus, Economy Flex, or even business class ...).
Often, buying an higher fare including luggage costs less than the lowest fare (not including luggage) + adding luggage. It is a violation of art. 10 [CE 80/2009](https://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/en/TXT/?uri=CELEX:32009R0080)?

Such law says airlines must offer the same fares on reservation systems where they’re present other than their own website, but it is widely disattended.

Comment: Cann you explain what is in the law and why you think this practice is a violation of it?

Comment: I edited the question

Comment: This is too general. I think it's likely that the discount online travel agencies you're checking aren't getting inventory not through reservation systems but via an airline consolidator. (They buy a bunch of tickets in bulk from the airline then resell them.) The reason is airlines don't pay ticket commissions anymore, but the site can make a markup from the consolidator fares. Have you checked with a reservation system directly, like at a travel agent's terminal?

Comment: This is true for OTA Booking.com too? (it seems Booking uses GotoGate). Thank you for the explanation, but the question is if that is legit or they're circumventing such law? Btw, yes, I contacted both airlines and the OTA and they didn't explain.